# Using Symfony2 Form without views

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am building a Rest Api and are also using Symfony2 forms for my put and post requests.

I have experienced that some of my post or put operations are starting to get very slow. I debugged and found that one of my forms is taking very long by transforming an "ID" to the view representation of an entity. The problematic field is this:

```
$builder->add('user', 'entity', array('class' => 'StregoUserBundle:User'))
```

When submitting the form and providing a value of "26" the viewtransformer fetches ALL! users in order to show them when rendering the form. (Choicelist)

I can avoid this when providing a choice array:

```
$builder->add('user', 'entity', array('class' => 'StregoUserBundle:User',
                                        'choices' => array()
                                        ));
```

This is having a major performance impact and I started doing this in all my "entity" form fields. The question would be if there is a general solution to completely disable view transformation?

*Update* 
I did not solve the problem since by providing an empty choice array, my submitted values are rejected. So I am still stuck with the task of disabling view transformers.

Comment: How many users do you have in your storage? How many columns of data does each user have? Do you have associations that are setup as eager loading?

Comment: FOS Userbundle + 7 fields, i have in my test database 7k users, but I am expecting way more in production. And no eager loading associations.

Answer (score 0):

well in theory you could just render an integer field instead of an entity field and use a data transformer.  you'd have a much easier time that way.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your best solution is to provide a form extension which will override the behavior of the entity form type. Then in this extension replace the default data transformers by your own implementation.

The documentation about form extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

As you will see, you can override the `buildForm` method and then remove all data transformers and add your own as you want.